# How to limit on distinct values and avoiding scan the whole table with order by in the query

Tags: mysql, sql

Say here's the table, with column A,B,C,D,E. I want limited distinct values from column A after order by column E.

I know if without order by, below query works:

```
set @num := 0, @pa = '';
select A, B, C, D, @num := if(@pa = A, @num, @num+1) as row_number, @pa := A as dummy
from table group by A having row_number <= 100;
```

But if 'order by E' is added to the end of the query, the 'order by' is only working on the result after the 100 rows are selected.

I know it works that sorting the table first and select the distinct 100 values from column A, but in this way the whole table is scanned. Since the whole table is very large, I don't want a whole scan on it.

Thus my question is how to sort it first and then select first 100 distinct values on column A without scanning the whole table.

-------- Update ----------

I tried

```
set @num := 0, @pa = '';
select A, B, C, D, @num := if(@pa = A, @num, @num+1) as row_number, @pa := A as dummy
from table where row_number <= 100 order by E;
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Why its doesn't work? dont have your data sorry? just asking. any return values

Comment: It has grammer issue. The query can't find 'row_number' in this way.

Comment: ok, so you dont have any problem now?

Comment: Yes, I do. I still don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
select * from (select A, B, C, D, E from table order by E) as temp 
group by A having count(A) <= 100
```

Comment: No, 'select A, B, C, D, E from table order by E' scans the whole table. And the result of this query is wrong.

Comment: Well, ordering by column E is going to use the index for this column. Which is sorted by default (B-tree). And from this sorted list you want only the first 100 distinct values for A, right ? May be this query will help `select distinct A, B, C, D from table order by E limit 100` ?

Comment: Yes, it almost works. But what if I want all the data of B,C,D those are with first distinct 100 values in column A, what I now can got is 'SELECT * from (select A from table group by A order by E) tmp inner join table on table.A = tmp.A'

Comment: Maybe this one `SELECT a,b,c,d,e FROM table WHERE a IN (SELECT a FROM table GROUP BY a ORDER BY e LIMIT 100) ORDER BY e` ?